# Facebook Graph Api Explorer Vs Facebook Graph Api C#

Tags: c#, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I'm having troubles on getting data from facebook's graph api explorer using an Access Token that someone gave me.

In the Graph Api Explorer at the developers Website I can see results to my queries, however when I call it via C# or Web Get Request, the **Data array comes empty**.

I've checked permissions on both ends (Developers website and Web Get Request) and they are different, but I still have the grant for read insights and ads on both.

**Developers Graph Api Explorer**

```
{   "data": [
     {
       "permission": "ads_read",
       "status": "granted"
     },
     {
       "permission": "read_insights",
       "status": "granted"
     },
     {
       "permission": "pages_show_list",
       "status": "granted"
     }   ] 
}
```

**Web Get Request**

```
{
    "data": [
       {
          "permission": "ads_read",
          "status": "granted"
       },
       {
          "permission": "read_insights",
          "status": "granted"
       }    ] 
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this "pages_show_list" permissions the reason I'm not getting anything on my C# web requests?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what was the problem.

The problem was that in my C# code I was not setting the API Version.

This:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/insights/page_stories?access_token=xxxx
```

is different from this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/insights/page_stories?access_token=xxxx
```